# Undo multiple files in Xcode without using SVN/Git

Tags: xcode

I replaced text in all files, which went wrong for me. I want to undo all the files which made the changes.

Comment: tough luck, my friend, but if you use __Time Machine__, you could use that in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to undo changes simultaneously in several files.

If you just did the replacement and you still have the Find and Replace query open, you can go through each file with a change manually and press **Undo** (<kbd>⌘Z</kbd>) once, that will revert all replacements.

Comment: Make sure xcode was not be closed else it lost all its backtrack path...lolx

Answer (score 0):

I could not undo multiple files from Xcode. I had to use SVN. I selected multiple files there and revert the local changes. All files status also turned to Unchanged for SVN.